Telegraf show reply message and copy to clipboard
I'm creating a bot in Telegram using Telegraf npm pkg and I need to achieve two things:

A message waiting for a response for the user. Using ctx.reply( won't achieve this



After clicking in something like this, I need the text to be copied to the clipboard

await ctx.telegram.sendMessage(
        ctx.message.chat.id,
        `Now you'll be able to copy to clipboard`,
        {
          reply_markup: Markup.inlineKeyboard([
            Markup.button.callback(
              " Copy Address",
              `copy_address xkxkxk`
            ),
          ]).reply_markup,
        }
      );

The documentation can be found here, but after going through it, I can't find this functionality https://github.com/feathers-studio/telegraf-docs/blob/master/README.md

The ForceReply reply markup can be used to achieve the your first goal. The code will be something like:
await ctx.reply("User will be forced to reply to this message.", {
    reply_markup: {
        force_reply: true,
    }
});


For the second question, it's not actually possible to copy a text into users clipboard just by tapping a button.
A workaround for this would be you can send a copiable text as a message, and prompt the user to copy the text. You can use one of these similar methods:
const text = "Please tap on the below address to copy\n\n<code>The Address To Be Copied</code>";
await ctx.reply(text, {
    parse_mode: "HTML",
});

// Or

const highlighted = 'Tap the copy button to copy the below address.\n\n<pre><code>The Address To Be Copied</code></pre>'
await ctx.reply(highlighted, {
    parse_mode: "HTML",
});

The output would be something like this:

Hope this helps!

on a different topic. when I'm using my own Context and I add a field to the object extending Conext, when I change between scenes, that field value isn't persisted. Do you know how to save the state of the context. I'm using something like this https://github.com/feathers-studio/telegraf-docs/blob/master/examples/scenes/scenes-with-custom-context-and-scene-session.ts


can be achieved by using force_reply

bot.command("test", async (ctx) => {
  if (ctx.chat?.id) {
    await ctx.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.chat?.id, `This is just a test`, {
      reply_markup: { force_reply: true },
    });
  } else {
    console.log("didn't make it");
  }
});

